# Getting current time and date in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get current time and date in the webpage , i am having the javascript code for it . not sure how to Implement in vue.js .I am attaching the code sample here.

html and plain js code:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <h2>JavaScript new Date()</h2>
        <p id="timestamp"></p>

        <script>
            var today = new Date();
            var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
            var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + 
            today.getSeconds();
            var dateTime = date+' '+time;
            document.getElementById("timestamp").innerHTML = dateTime;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

i need to implement in vue.js where should i include whether in mounted or computed or method?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. *mounted* when you want to execute it when the component is loaded, *computed* when you want it to update whenever the component is updated, *method* when you want to update it whenever the function is called. Based on your current code, I would say *mounted*.

Comment: i just need to place in my webpage thatsit just like an element

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because the time at present isn't depend on any data variable, so we can write it in **methods**, and call in **created**

Read more about **computed** and **methods** [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

You can copy and run it in [CodingGround](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_vuejs_editor.php)

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
      <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
         <h1>{{ timestamp }}</h1>
      </div>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         var vue_det = new Vue({
            el: '#intro',
            data: {
               timestamp: ""
            },
            created() {
                setInterval(this.getNow, 1000);
            },
            methods: {
                getNow: function() {
                    const today = new Date();
                    const date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
                    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                    const dateTime = date +' '+ time;
                    this.timestamp = dateTime;
                }
            }
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to get update of this time without refreshing page ?

Comment: @saran I have updated my answer, you can test it =))

Comment: this answer works but is not a good practice and will make your app slow, you should find a way to not need the time from a js call all the time if possible.

Comment: To have seconds formatted properly, change `const time` line to `const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + (today.getSeconds() < 10 ?  "0" + today.getSeconds() : today.getSeconds()) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a component, like `Dashboard.vue`, you can use a getter:

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <h1>{{ timestamp }}</h1>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Dashboard extends Vue {
  get timestamp() {
    const today = new Date();
    const date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    const timestamp = date + ' ' + time;
    return timestamp;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this code in vue js and You can use this way

```
var first_time = '09:00:00'
var today = new Date()
var now_date = (today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + today.getDate());
var now_time = (today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()).toString()

if (now_time === first_time){
console.log('true')
}else(){
console.log('false')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the current day with this:

```
"(new Date(Date.now() - (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().substring(0, 10)"
```